# Data on foreclosed IndyMac mortages after WestOne Bank acquired assets?

Tags: united-states, financial-crisis

With the recent appointment of Steven Mnuchin for Treasure Secretary in the upcoming Trump administration in the US, I've heard renewed discussion of the foreclosures on holders of mortgages originated by IndyMac.

I've heard the reporting about IndyMac engaged in "predatory" mortgage lending behaviors. I also believe that it takes two to tango, and I don't want to see one party's choices swept under the rug so as to make them look blameless, unless it's indeed an accurate statement. (And I believe that, in situations like this, statistics speak far louder than rhetoric.)

So, **I'm wondering if there's publicly-available data about these foreclosures**, in particular if there's any record of the frequency of fraudulently stated income on these mortgage applications, or perhaps of "doctored" mortgages (such as those modified after being signed, say) or anything else that might shed meaningful light on the role that both parties (borrower and originator) played in these mortgages.

I have no particular expectations about such data, except the possibility that something about that collection of mortgages made it appear to Mnuchin (if indeed the decision was primarily his...I don't know about that) or OneWest Bank to be sufficiently forclose'able to warrant the acquisition of the mortgage assets.

Apologies if I use any terms incorrectly; I'm not terribly familiar with the world of mortgages. (Or a lot of the pieces relevant to this question, frankly.)